# Could i use maven profile to swith between different value application.properties

Tags: maven

I have application-prod.yml application-dev.yml, and  application.properties which containing just one line code like below

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

for maven production build, it should use  spring.profiles.active=prod , then it will build with application-prod.yml, for development build, it should use spring.profiles.active=dev, then maven
will use application-dev.yml to build
could I use pom.xml's different profile to do switch for this value switch in applicaiton.properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Maven property for this, reference it in your yml file (with `${...}`) and filter the resource (i.e. the yml file) with the maven resources plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're after is "externalized configuration". According to the excellent [12factor](https://12factor.net) guidelines, it is best not to keep such config inside your code-repository.

Refer to [the relevant](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) section in the Spring Boot manual to see which options you have (and there are many). What it comes down to is that you provide your `application.yml/properties` file on the filesystem and your application will read it from there, rather than from the classpath.

Also, note that spring-profiles are not meant to be used to distinguish between development environments, but rather to put the application in different functional modes (e.g. to enable or disable specific features).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content of your properties file changed at build time, then you can use Maven filtering. Maven filtering allows to replace a placeholder in your properties (or yaml) file by values from Maven properties.

Assuming you have a property in your POM called `targetEnv`, which might have either the value `dev` or `prod` (depending on the active Maven profile), then you can refer it in your properties file (or yaml file) by using the following syntax :

```
spring.profiles.active=@targetEnv@
```

However, if you want to follow Spring Boot recommandations, it is better to enable and disable the Spring profiles by the means of environment variables in your target environment. For instance, you can use an environment variable `spring.profiles.active` with the desired value and it will override the value in your properties file.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to define a custom property in each of your Maven profiles and set their values to match with suffixes of corresponding properties files that you want to load with a particular profile.

   ```
   <profile>
     <id>dev</id>
     <properties>
       <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
     </properties>
     <activation>
       <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
     </activation>
   </profile>
   <profile>
     <id>release</id>
     <properties>
       <activatedProperties>release</activatedProperties>
     </properties>
   </profile>
   ```
2. Next, in the build section of the same file, configure filtering for the Resources Plugin. That will allow you to insert properties defined in the previous step into any file in the resources directory, which is the subsequent step.

   ```
   <build>
   <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           <filtering>true</filtering>
       </resource>
   </resources>
   …
   </build>
   ```
3. Finally, add the following line to the application.properties.

   ```
   spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
   ```

For more details, please see [spring boot properties per maven profile](http://dolszewski.com/spring/spring-boot-properties-per-maven-profile/)

For official guide to load from external config[Load from external Config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)